# finding the center of a circle given 3 points

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we have three complex numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3$ which are non-collinear. What is the best way to find the center of the circle that contains these three points ?

Comment: It would be done the same way as finding the circumcenter of a triangle from 3 coordinate points.

Comment: I have no idea why they related the other is different question

Comment: contains = all 3 points on the circumference? what guarantees it exists?

Comment: You can think of the complex number as a pair of coordinates, no?  Then you could do it the same way as the linked question.

Comment: I notice that if $a_3$ moves around while $a_1$ and $a_2$ stay fixed, then the center moves along a line although $a_3$ moves about in a plane.  That rules out any possibility of the center being any sort of analytic function of $a_1,a_2,a_3$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the equation of the perpendicular bisectors of a pair of lines(any pair) of the triangle formed by connecting the points. The intersection of these bisectors will be the center of the circle.

Comment: OK, so far, but I won't be surprised if the center is a closed-form function of the three points. ${}\qquad{}$